# How to fix ReferenceError: System is not defined when router not found or not defined in angular2 routes?

Tags: angular, router

here is my routing code:

```
const dashboard_routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: ApplicationComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'product', component: ProductHomeComponent,
            children:[
                {
                    path:'',component: ProductIndex
                },
                {
                    path: 'new', component: NewProductComponent
                },
            ]

        },



        {
            path: '', component: DashboardIndexComponent
        }
    ]

}
]
```

and when i enter "/dashboard/product" or "/dashboard/product/new"   in the browser
its worked
but when i enter "/dashboard/product/xxx" or any other character after "/product/*"

a problem happend:
 [exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3axw.png)

but if  i enter '/dashboard/*' ,app returns 404  ,its true;

here is 404 route code:

```
const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: 'src/module/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
    }
];

const appRoutes: Routes = [

    ...dashboardRoutes,

    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },

    {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}

]

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

how to fix this problem ??

Comment: how do you host your application? `angular-cli` or in production on an `IIS`  or `apache` or whatever? :)

Comment: @mxii webpack-server  for dev ,nginx for production

Comment: didnt know them both, but you need to redirect all "URLs" to "/" .. maybe there are some plugins or addons.. named like `url rewrite` or similiar.

Comment: @mxii i have fixed it ; because the lazy load router didn't  be known before i reached the '/dashboard'